# SQL Server Plan Cache Suddenly Misbehaving

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm running soak tests at the moment and keep coming up against a wierd issue that I've never seen in the past.  I've spent quite a while investigating the issue and so far not got to be bottom of it.

At some point during the test (sometimes 1 hour in, other times 4+ hours) the SQL Server machine starts maxing it's CPU.  This always corresponds with a sharp decrease in DB cache memory and increase in free memory.

The signs obviously point at memory pressure and it seems that I can sometimes trigger this event by running a particularly heavy query.

I can understand why the plan cache is being flushed however the aspects of this that are confusing me are:

- After the plan cache is flushed and my meaty query finishes there is plenty of free memory (even after further increasing the amount of memory SQL Server is allowed) the plan cache doesn't seem to recover.  I'm left with loads of free memory which isn't helping anyone.
- If I stop my soak test and then re-run it immediatly then things go back to normal, the plan cache grows as expected.  SQL Server does not need restarted or to have any settings altered.

After the cache flush the cache hit ratio is still OK-ish, ~90% however this is much lower than the ~99% I am seeing before the flush and really hurting the CPU.

Before the flush a trace of cache misses, inserts and hits looks normal enough.  Pre-flush the only issue I see is a non-parameterised ad-hoc query that's being inserted into the cache very frequently however even with this it's a very simple query which has a low cost so would expect these to be flushed from the cache ahead of most other things.

Post flush I'm seeing a very high number of inserts followed immediately by numerous misses on the same object (i.e. stored procedures), and thus memory consumption for the cache remains low.

You can see from the yellow line in the shot of my counters below that the cache memory usage drops off and stays low yet the free memory (royal blue) stays fairly high.

[image: Performance Counters]

**EDIT**

After looking into this issue for another good while a pattern that keeps appearing is that if I push the server to it's limit for a short time (adding load above what the soak test is producing) then SQL Server seems to get itself into a mess which it can't recover from on it's own.

The number of connections to the server sharply increases when it hits the point of maximum pressure (I'm assuming due to it not being able to deal with requests quickly enough so new connections are needed to deal with the "constant" flow of requests).  This backlog is then placing further pressure on the server which it doesn't appear to be able to recover from.

Now, I'm still puzzled by the metrics.  I could accept this as purely a server resource issue if the new connections seemed to be eating up memory, further slowing processing, causing new connections, etc.  What I am seeing though is that there is plenty of free memory but SQL Server isn't using it for the plan cache.  Because of this it's spending more time compiling, upping CPU and things spiral out of control.

It feels like the connections are the key part of this problem.  As mentioned before if I restart the test everything goes back to normal.  I've since found that putting the DB into single user mode for a few seconds so that all test related connections die, waiting a few seconds and then going back to multi-user mode resolves the issue.  I've tried just killing all active connections based on SPID however it seems there needs to be a pause of a few seconds in order for the server to recover and start using the plan cache properly.

See screenshot below of my counters.  I'm trying to push the server over the top up to ~02:33:15 and I set to single user mode at ~02:34:30 and then multi-user mode a few seconds after.

Purple line is user connections, thick red is compilations p/s, bright green is cache memory, aqua connection memory, greyish/brown is free memory.

[image: Caching Issue with Reset]

Comment: Can you post a link to the image? Someone will probably edit it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's been a long circular road but the best answer I currently have for this is that this issue is due to resource constraints and the unfortunate choices that SQL Server makes in relation to the plan cache for *my particular circumstances*.  I'm not saying SQL Server is wrong, just that for my needs at this time I don't think it's making the right decisions.

I've adjusted my soak test so that if the DB server comes under pressure it pulls on the reigns a bit and drops some connections, until such time that the server comes back under control and the additional connections can be reestablished.  The process of SQL Server getting itself back in order can take a few minutes but it does happen!

It seems that the server was getting itself into a vicious cycle, where it was coming under pressure, dropping cached plans and then having to spend more on recompiling these plans later than it gained by dropping them in the first place.  This lead to things spiraling out of control and everything grinding to a halt.

In my particular case there is a very high cache hit ratio (above 99.5%) and due to the soak test basically doing the same thing repeatedly for hours for loads of users the cache is very well used.  If the cache weren't so well used then SQL Server would have quite possibly made the right choice by dropping plans but I don't think it did here.